# bumper plugin does not work when using simbody physics

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I use ODE physics in gazebo, bumper plugin works correctly. But, when use simbody physics, bumper plugin does now work, has no output.

simbody does not support bumper plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7794/bumper-plugin-does-not-work-when-using-simbody-physics/) by [Byeong-Kyu Ahn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1075/byeong-kyu-ahn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That's correct. The integration of Simbody with Gazebo currently doesn't not support the output of contact information.

Here is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1406) to track this problem.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2015-01-07**:
Actually try [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/865/simbody-not-integrated-with-contactmanager)